# What does this split subject phrase, "it might all have started", imply?

Tags: idioms, nuance

A well-known British writer has this:

> [to question] how it might all have started

To my non-native English speaker ear this sounds a bit off; I'd have said

> [to question] how it all might have started

Is there a difference in tone between the two variants that I might be missing? What sounds more natural?

Comment: There's a difference in euphony if not in practical meaning.

Comment: ... Yes, as Tim implies, the less logical-looking variant sounds more attractive. It's surprising that [the Google 5-grams for "how it might all have" / "how it all might have"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+it+might+all+have%2Chow+it+all+might+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show that the less euphonic variant seems twice as popular.

Comment: If you think "all have started" goes together then you don't break it up with the word "might".

Answer (score 0):

… how it all might have started
… how it might all have started

A fine point of meaning. I have also considered a close variant such as:

… how it might partly have started
May draw attention to the various ways in which the matter may have started. *Partly* is acting adverbially on *start*

… how it partly might have started
May draw attention to the role parts of it played in starting the matter. *Partly* is acting in an adjectival manner on *it*

But this is straining to find nuances that, while possible in this variant, do not seem to work with  your own example. I therefore suggest that there is no significant difference there.